# Outputting the parent process ID using ```Echo $$```

Tags: c, echo

I wrote the following C function that prints the PID of a parent process;

```
#include <stdio.h>                                           
#include <unistd.h>                                           
#include <sys/types.h>                                        
/**                                                           
 * main - PPID      
 *                                                            
 * Return: Always 0                                           
 */                                                           
int main(void)                                                
{                                                             
        pid_t my_ppid;                                        
                                                              
        my_ppid = getppid();                                  
        printf("%u\n", my_ppid);                              
        return (0);                                           
}
```

I compiled the same program using;
`gcc -Werror -pedantic pid.c -o myppid && ./myppid`.
Running the program several times in the same shell using  `./myppid` returns the same Parent Process ID each time.

Now; using `echo $$ ./myppid` several times produces the same constant Parent Process ID each time. Why?

Comment: Because it's the same shell that's the parent process all the time? Why would you expect a new parent pid each time you run the program?

Comment: Your shell is the parent process.  Since you're only running one shell, you have only that one parent process.  If you want to force a different parent, run the command in a sub-shell.  It's not clear why you'd care about that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell process does not die or get a new process id when you start programs from it - and the shell process *is* the parent process of the  programs your start from it. Looking at a snapshot of the process tree (`pstree`), it could look like this:

```
  ⋮
  └─sshd,34822
      └─bash,34823
          └─myppid,432966
```

Here, `myppid` would print `34823`.

The next time you start your program from the same shell, you may see this:

```
  ⋮
  └─sshd,34822
      └─bash,34823
          └─myppid,315652
```

Again, `myppid` would print `34823` - the shell lives on.

Also, when you do `echo $$` in the shell, you are printing the *current* process id - which for your shell is `34823` (in my example) - the same as the parent process id of `myppid`.

Comment: This has definitely helped. Thanks!

Comment: @greezy_ke Glad to hear it! You're welcome! I also made [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Gq5xEhsdq) to show you a shell simulation.